# Explanation of subspace strategy regarding CG described in Golub's book

Tags: linear-algebra, conjugate-gradient

I was wondering about the last paragraph in *Matrix Computations (4th edition)* by Golub, Chapter 11 (11.3.3), specifically his explanation of subspace strategy for Conjugate Gradient.

> Note that in Algorithm 11.3.1, the step-k optimization is over the affine space $x_k + span\{\nabla\phi(x_k)\}$.
>
> Given that $Ax_0 \approx b$, our plan is to produce a nested sequence of subspaces
>
> $\space S1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \subset \cdots $
>
> that satisfy $dim(S_k) =k$ and to solve the problem
>   $\underset{x\in x_0 + S_k}{min} \phi(x)$
>   each step along the way.
>
> If $x_k$ is the step-k minimizer, then because of the nesting we have $\phi(x_1)\geq \phi(x_2) \geq \cdots \phi(x_n)=\phi(x_*)$. since $S_n = \mathbb{R}^n $, we ultimately obtain $x_* = A^{-1}b$. Even though this is a finite-step solution framework, it may not be attractive if $n$ is extremely large. The challenge is to find a subspace sequence that promotes rapid decrease in the value of $\phi$, for then we may be able to terminate the iteration long before $k$ equals $n$.
>
> With this goal in mind we note that at $x_k$ the function $\phi$ decreases most rapidly in the direction of the negative gradient. Thus, it makes sense to choose $S_{k+1}$ so that it includes $x_k$ and the gradient $g_k = \nabla\phi(x_k) = Ax_k -b$. This strategy guarantees that $x_{k+1}$ is at least as good as a steepest descent update:
>
> $\underset{x\in x_0 + S_{k+1}}{min} \phi(x_{k+1} \leq \underset{\mu \in \mathbb R}{min}\space \phi(x_k -\mu g_k )$
>
> If $x_0$ is an initial guess and we define $g_0 = Ax_0 -b$, then since $\nabla \phi(x_k) \in span \{x_k,Ax_k\}$ it follows that the only way to satisfy this requirement is to set:
>
> $S_k = \mathcal{K}(A,g_0,k) = span\{g_0, Ag_0, A^2g_0,\dots, A^{k-1}g_0\}$

Why does Golub write that $\nabla \phi(x_k)\in span(x_k, Ax_k)$?

I don't understand how this is possible since $\nabla\phi(x_k) = Ax_k -b$, how do you get $b$ from $span(x_k, Ax_k)$?

I think there's something trivial that I'm missing here...

Comment: It might just be some kind of typo. I know that the end result is correct, but with $A=I$ and $x_0 = e_1$, this cannot hold for any $b$.